# vstest.console.exe generate cover for only Moq.dll

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-coverage, vstest.console.exe, runsettings

I am trying to generate code coverage report using **vstest.console.exe**.  I am also using **.runsettings** file and passing it as a parameter.

Whatever I am trying to do, it generates a coverage report for only moq.dll.

I am sharing below the full text of command parameters I am running and also content of .runsettings file. Any idea, where am I doing something wrong?

**Command:**

> vstest.console.exe
>   "C:\Xyz.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Xyz.Tests.dll" /InIsolation
>   /EnableCodeCoverage /settings:CodeCoverage.runsettings

**CodeCoverage.runsettings** file content:

```
<RunSettings>
<DataCollectionRunSettings>
  <DataCollectors>
    <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" enabled="false">
      <Configuration>
        <CodeCoverage>
        </CodeCoverage>
      </Configuration>
    </DataCollector>
  </DataCollectors>
</DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Image of generated code coverage report:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same behavior, but fortunately I found out a solution:

### Open Visual Studio Test task and:

Uncheck **`Code coverage enabled`** flag

Put **`--collect:"Code Coverage"`** in Other console options

### Edit **.csproj** file of project, containing the tested classes and:

Add **`<DebugType>full</DebugType>`** in **`<PropertyGroup>`** section

### To avoid moq.dll in Code Coverage results:

Add **`<ModulePath>.*moq.dll</ModulePath>`** in `<ModulePaths> ->  <Exclude>` section of .runsettings file

Here is my .runsettings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <MaxCpuCount>0</MaxCpuCount>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <!-- Match assembly file paths: -->
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*moq.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*TestAdapter.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

And please, check out https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/92905/net-core-unit-testing-code-coverage.html link

Comment: Thanks Alxander, this solution worked for me. Seems the most important part is adding <DebugType>full</DebugType> to the project.